# Why do I see a black screen after boot until I press Alt+F1

Tags: ubuntu, terminal, boot, grub

I just installed Ubuntu 16.04.7 from [mini.iso](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/MinimalCD). It's a VIA Nano U3500 @ 1GHz with 1 GB RAM and 4 GB HDD and from my research it *seems* this is the most appropriate Ubuntu for such a machine.

On the menu screen where you select installable components I only checked the OpenSSH server, and I'm *assuming* it won't install any graphical environment then.

Now when I boot the machine I only see a black screen. Only when I press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> I get a login prompt. There are 5 more terminals with <kbd>F2</kbd> to <kbd>F6</kbd>. With <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd> I get a screen with a slightly bolder font (I think it's called "the VGA font") that says `/dev/sda1: clean ... files, ... blocks`.

<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F8</kbd>, <kbd>F9</kbd>, etc. do nothing.

I noticed that when I press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> *during* the boot process (the machine takes about 10 seconds to fully boot) I get to see a few boot messages, like `[<timestamp>] [sdb] assuming drive cache: write through` and then immediately I get the login.

If I hold shift at the beginning of the boot process, I get the GRUB menu with "Ubuntu" selected, if I then confirm with Enter the booting runs again with a black screen.

What would I have to do to be able to watch the usual boot messages and see the login without pressing any keys after boot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, Ubuntu will boot with the kernel parameters `quiet splash`.  I found getting rid of these will avoid the problem you describe.  I believe I only experienced this problem myself on UEFI based devices (and not on BIOS based devices which is all that the Ubuntu `mini.iso` supports).

This will clear the `quiet splash` parameters for the next boot.

```
sed -i -e 's/^GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=.*/GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=""/' /etc/default/grub
update-grub
```

I have also experienced your problem when graphical libraries get installed.  In that situation the solution was to change the boot target from `graphical.target` to `multi-user.target`.

```
systemctl set-default multi-user.target
```

Also, you should **not** be using 16.04.  That version is End-of-Life.  I would be surprised if 20.04 did not work just as well on the hardware.  The `mini.iso` is a bit hidden as it is being phased out, but it can be downloaded from http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal/main/installer-amd64/current/legacy-images/netboot/

Comment: Good catch about the CPU. When I bought it the machine was listed as having a VIA Eden CPU which is 32 bit and I think 20.04 doesn't have a 32 bit version. However the VIA Nano CPU that is *actually* in the machine indeed seems to be 64 bit.